# How to login with either username or email in an ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 6.0 project. I have added the Identity library which added Razor pages.

The Register and Login work fine as long as the UserName and the Email are the same. However, I would like to have a UserName as a plain string and the email as a typical email and the user could log in with either the Username or the Email.

I have customized the Register page wherein I collect both the UserName and Email. I don't see any sample code where it could be achieved. I see a few sample codes that don't collect the UserName from the user. Instead in the code, UserName is saved as the Email. Essentially both values will be identical.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the username as a plain string and the email as a typical email, then you need to enter a `UserName` property and use it as the `UserName` field of the database when registering, because Identity will store `Email` as the `UserName` field by default.

In `Regirster.cshtml.cs`, you need to add a property in `InputModel` and store it to database in `OnPostAsync` method:

```
public class InputModel
{
    //other properties
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, change

```
await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
```

to

```
await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.UserName, CancellationToken.None);
```

in `OnPostAsync` method.

In `Register.cshtml`, add a input for entering UserName:

```
<div class="form-floating">
    <input asp-for="Input.UserName" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" />
    <label asp-for="Input.UserName"></label>
    <span asp-validation-for="Input.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

And if you want to log in with either the `Username` or the `Email`, you need to make some adjustments to the `InputModel` and `OnPostAsync` method in `Login.cshtml.cs`.

The default InputModel:

```
public class InputModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
            
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Remove `EmailAddress` annotation and define Display text for `Email`:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Username/Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Then change `OnPostAsync` method like below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

   if (Input.Email.IndexOf('@') > -1)
   {
        //Validate email format
        string emailRegex = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
                               @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
                                  @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$";
        Regex re = new Regex(emailRegex);
        if (!re.IsMatch(Input.Email))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Email is not valid");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //validate Username format
        string userNameRegex = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
        Regex re = new Regex(userNameRegex);
        if (!re.IsMatch(Input.Email))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Username is not valid");
        }
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userName = Input.Email;
        if (userName.IndexOf('@') > -1)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                userName = user.UserName;
            }
        }
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

**Edit:**

If you get the following error: `The name '_userManager' does not exist in the current context`, it is because you did not inject `UserManager` into `LoginModel`:

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

    public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hi Chen, thanks for the detailed answer. However the code you provided doesn't compile. This line fails: var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email); with the error message, "The name '_userManager' does not exist in the current context". That's because the LoginModel page has only SignInManager and not the UserManager.

Comment: Hi @Massey, I updated my answer, it was my mistake, I forgot to add this step in the answer.